# Mapbox change zoom on click event

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a map where the starting zoom level is 5. When a user clicks on a point, I want the map to go to that point and and change the zoom to level 10. I'm using the flyTo() method to center the map on the point. How can I change the zoom level?

Answer (score 9):

I realised I can add zoom to flyTo() like:

```
map.flyTo({center: e.features[0].geometry.coordinates, zoom:10});
```

I'll take my downvote